# Pgfplots grid lines to terminate at integer boundaries

Tags: pgfplots, grids

Is there a `pgfplots` styling that I can use to get the grid lines to stop at integer boundaries and not extend from `xmin ... xmax` (and `ymin ... ymax`)?

The desired output is shown on the right, which uses a custom macro to draw the grid):

[image]

### Notes:

- Don't need an automated solution -- explicitly providing the `xmin ... xmax` (and `ymin ... ymax`) for the grid would be fine.  Seems as if I could have a different `xmin ... xmax` (and `ymin ... ymax`) for the grid and the axis that would do it.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand*{\MyPgfplotsGrid}[4]{%
    \foreach \xCoord in {#1,...,#2} {% Vertical Grid Lines
        \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, help lines] coordinates {(\xCoord,#3) (\xCoord,#4)};
    }%
    \foreach \yCoord in {#3,...,#4} {% Horizontal Grid Lines
        \addplot [mark=none, forget plot, help lines] coordinates {(#1,\yCoord) (#2,\yCoord)};
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    yminorgrids=true,
    minor tick num=1,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-3.5, ymax=3.5,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %xmajorgrids=true,
    %ymajorgrids=true,
    %yminorgrids=true,
    minor tick num=1,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-3.5, ymax=3.5,
]
    \MyPgfplotsGrid{-3}{3}{-3}{3}%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would setting the `(x|y)m(in|ax)` to integer values, and adding `axis line style={shorten >=-0.5cm,shorten <=-0.5cm}`  be sufficient? (Needs some adjusting of the bounding box.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That doesn't quite produce the same results though. But that would suffice for me if the bounding box could be adjusted.  Also, think that there is an issue with specifying `cm` units for the shorten, as there are no other `cm` specifications for the axis. Really want to extend by `(axis cs: -0.5, 0)` and `(axis cs: +0.5, 0)` for the `x` axis (and similarly for the `y` axis).

Comment: Ah yes, good point about the units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit crude, but you could draw the axis lines manually, with

```
execute at end axis={
         \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:-3.5,0) -- (axis cs:3.5,0);
         \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:0,-3.5) -- (axis cs:0,3.5);
   }
```

Requires `clip mode=individual` as well, and `axis line style={draw=none}` to turn off drawing the 'real' axis.

You can of course wrap all the settings in a style to perhaps reduce a bit of clutter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{MyGrid/.style={xmin=-#1,xmax=#1,ymin=-#1,ymax=#1,
%            xtick={-#1,...,#1},ytick={-#1,...,#1},  % don't know if you want this
             xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,
             yminorgrids=true,minor tick num=1,
             axis lines=middle,
             axis line style={draw=none},
             clip mode=individual,
             execute at end axis={
               \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:-#1-0.5,0) -- (axis cs:#1+0.5,0);
               \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:0,-#1-0.5) -- (axis cs:0,#1+0.5);}
             }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[MyGrid=3]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To specify `xmin`/`xmax`/`ymin`/`ymax` separately, one could use `style n args` to define a style that takes four arguments. All four have to be specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{MyGrid/.style n args={4}{xmin=-#1,xmax=#2,ymin=-#3,ymax=#4,
             xtick={-#1,...,#2},ytick={-#3,...,#4}, 
             xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,
             axis lines=middle,
             axis line style={draw=none},
             clip mode=individual,
             execute at end axis={
               \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:-#1-0.5,0) -- (axis cs:#2+0.5,0);
               \draw [-stealth] (axis cs:0,-#3-0.5) -- (axis cs:0,#4+0.5);}
             }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[MyGrid={3}{2}{1}{4}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. Will try it tomorrow on my real test case. Also, think it would be better to allow for 4 parameters instead of only one so that one can control separately `xmim`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax`.