# How to draw a grid with pgfplots which terminal lines start and finish at the limit points of the x and y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a particular option that I can add to my code bellow to draw a grid lines that start and end at integer boundaries of the x and y-axis.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines =center,   
        grid=major,                                     
        grid style={dotted, cyan},
        anchor=origin,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel =$y$,  % Set the labels
        xmin= -4, xmax= 4, 
        ymin=-4, ymax=4, 
        xtick={ -3,-2, ...,3}, 
        ytick={-3, -2, ...,3},
        color=cyan
    ]
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Grid with pgfplots]

Comment: Does adding ticks at those locations help?

Comment: Related: [Pgfplots grid lines to terminate at integer boundaries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249492)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, I think. The grid is drawn anywhere there is a tick, so you can add the endpoints into your `xtick` and `ytick` commands:

```
xtick={-4,-3,...,4},
ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
```

I suspect that's not what you want though, because that will add the tick labels at those points as well. Rather than specify the tick labels for every tick, it might be easier to use the `extra ticks` to add grid lines:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dotted, cyan},
        anchor=origin,
        xlabel = $x$, ylabel =$y$,  % Set the labels
        xmin= -4, xmax= 4,
        ymin=-4, ymax=4,
        xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
        extra x ticks={-4, 4},
        extra y ticks={-4, 4},
        extra tick style={grid=major, grid style={dotted, cyan}},
        extra x tick labels={},
        extra y tick labels={},
        color=cyan
    ]
    \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how, if I want to add another extra tick (pi for example) with no vertical line wich passes through this abscissa.

Comment: @user22432 It would be better to ask a new question about that...

Comment: Done! Here is the question  [Grid lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269386/22432)