# Error in grid of log scaled .tikz file generated by matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz, ticks

I have generated a tikz file by matlab2tikz. The figure has grids in log mode. However, it does not show the grid at 2x10^7 although xmax=3x10^7, as shown here:

[image]

When I increase the xmax=4x10^7, it shows all grids correctly, as shown here:

[image]

Is there a simple way to add the grid at 2x10^7 when xmax=3x10^7?

Is it a bug?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.33000,0.10000}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.93000,0.69000,0.13000}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.229in,
height=2.122in,
at={(0.542in,0.286in)},
scale only axis,
unbounded coords=jump,
xmode=log,
xmin=100000,
xmax=30000000,
xminorticks=true,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Frequency [Hz]},
ymin=30,
ymax=105,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Current [dBµA]},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
120000  99.0045009826914\\
168000.000000003    94.0329250554461\\
216000  88.1265671014924\\
264000.000000003    85.0753459548058\\
311999.999999998    83.8360872591418\\
360000  82.5027662489753\\
407999.999999995    81.2608865356361\\
2963000.00000003    56.0899171397631\\
3011000.00000004    54.2962201226581\\
3441999.99999999    54.623001576856\\
3490000.00000003    53.7238229832034\\
22334999.9999997    47.3027911014257\\
22395999.9999999    49.7722178053978\\
22529000.0000002    47.9630513502279\\
22574999.9999998    50.1404369627122\\
22605000    47.6690243291318\\
29901000.0000002    52.7283448389326\\
30000000    52.073623376038\\
};
\addlegendentry{I}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added an extra tick based on the following link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269386/how-to-add-an-extra-tick-without-adding-a-new-line-to-the-grid  . This the code which I have added : extra x ticks={20e6},
extra tick style={grid=major, grid style={dashed}}, extra x tick labels={},