# Removing a grid line and shortening the remaining grid lines in a pgfplots display

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot of the parabola `y = x^{2} - 5x + 4` over the interval `[-2, 7]` and a normal line to it.  I have grid lines spaced the default 5 units apart. Since the parabola and the line intersect at `(4,0)`, I have `extra x ticks={4}` in the code to mark it, and I have `extra x tick labels={$\scriptstyle4$}` to label it.  An extra vertical grid line is plotted there.  How do I remove it?

I like the lengths that I have for the `x`-axis and `y`-axis.  The grid lines are drawn too long.  If I reduce the values for `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, or `ymax`, the grid lines are shortened as well as the axes.  How do I just shorten the grid lines?

Also, I don't like the display for labeling the vertex.  If I label the vertex, I want to express the coordinates as fractions.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!25}, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7.5,xmax=12.5,
    ymin=-7,ymax=22.5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:20,
    xticklabels={, , , , , ,},
    yticklabels={, , , , , , ,},
    extra x ticks={4},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white, circle, inner sep=1.5pt}},
    extra x tick labels={$\scriptstyle4$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=-2:7] {x^2 - 5*x + 4} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize]{$y=x^{2}-5x+4$};
\addplot[samples=2, domain=-7.5:12.5, latex-latex] {(-1/3)*x + 4/3} node[anchor=east, pos=0, font=\footnotesize]{$y=-\dfrac{1}{3}x+\dfrac{4}{3}$};

\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill] (2.5,-2.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\tiny] at (2.5,-2.5){$\left(\dfrac{5}{2}, -\dfrac{9}{4}\right)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the site works best when you ask one question per, ... well, per question, really.

Answer (score 4):

I googled `extra x ticks grid line` and got to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269386/) which solves your main problem.

So the trick is to change the style of the `extra x tick`:

```
extra x tick style={grid=none},
```

In your example it will look like this:

```
% [...]
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
    extra x tick style={grid=none}, % <--- I added this!
]
% [...]
```

Which leads to this output:

[image]

**Note**
I added these style options in order that you can see it in the picture:

```
major grid style={line width = 0.5pt,red},
axis line style={line width = 1pt},
```

Comment: I could draw each grid line individually and get exactly what I want.  It wouldn't be much extra coding.  I would like to use the `grid` option, though, to get more familiar with the `axis` environment.

Comment: @Adelyn What misspelling do you mean and what does it have to do with the acceptance of the answer? I don't get it. In addition, I did not write a comment here. I assume you mean my answer.

Comment: You want to say "... you can 'better' see it in the picture."

Comment: @Adelyn Is still something missing?

Comment: Yes, I am still waiting for an explanation for shortening the grid lines without adjusting the axes.

Comment: @Adelyn I'm not sure you can, but what's wrong with using `shorten` in the `axis line style`? An alternative could be to draw the axis lines manually, as in [Pgfplots grid lines to terminate at integer boundaries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252073).

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I could also draw the grid lines manually, which is what I am prone to do if I have to draw any of these lines manually.  What code would you suggest for using `shorten`?

Comment: @Adelyn More or less the exactly same thing that you have posted in the question ...

Comment: @Torbjørn T.   I am guessing that `axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt}` lengthens each side of the `x`-axis by 7.5pt.  How do I lengthen each side of the `y`-axis by 7.5pt?

Comment: @Adelyn I don't quite see why you would think that. By the way, the manual is an *excellent* reference. The description of `axis line style` says _A command which appends key-value-list to **all** axis line appearance styles._ I.e., it applies to both x- and y-axis. (Which you can see if you look at the output of your code.)

Answer (score 1):

I will not add `extra x ticks` at all. Instead it I suggest to label sloped line cross the x-axes point with ordinary node. With its removing and some other measures the code become more simple:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
%\usepackage{tikz}% it is load by pgfplots
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}% not needed in this particular case
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    tbox/.style = {font=\tiny},% <-- added
    fbox/.style = {font=\footnotesize}% <-- added 
                        ]
\begin{axis}[width=4in,
    grid,% <-- changed
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!50}, axis equal image, 
    clip=false,
%
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-7.5,xmax=12.5,
    ymin=-7,  ymax=22.5,
    xticklabels={empty},% <-- changed
    yticklabels={empty},% <-- changed
%
%    extra x ticks={4}, % <-- removed
%    extra x tick style={xticklabel style={...}}, % <-- removed
%    extra x tick labels={$\scriptstyle4$},% <-- removed
%
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={anchor=north west},% <-- changed
    ylabel style={anchor=south west} % <-- changed
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-2:7] {x^2 - 5*x + 4} node[fbox,right]{$y=x^{2}-5x+4$};
\addplot[samples=2,  domain=12.5:-7.5, latex-latex] {(-1/3)*x + 4/3} node[fbox,left]{$y=-\dfrac{1}{3}x+\dfrac{4}{3}$}; % <-- changed

\draw[fill] (4,0)       circle [radius=1.5pt] node[tbox,below] {4};
\draw[fill] (2.5,-2.25) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[tbox,below] {$\left(\dfrac{5}{2}, -\dfrac{9}{4}\right)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
As far as I see how the `extra x ticks` is used, I assume, that this coordinate is known in advance and it is designate only with labels. So I conclude, that this point can be designates as other points in graph: by node. Therefore I suggest, that don't employ `extra x ticks` with all necessary complications that it appear as desired but rather use simple node.

In suggestion I didn't bother with fancy lookout of graph. The colors or line thickness is simple to changed to own taste or some other wish.

All other changes in above MWE in comparison to MWE in question are designate with `% <-- ....` in code with comment, what is difference (changed, added). They are:

- in preamble is removed `tikz` (since it is loaded by `pgfplots`) and TikZ libraries
- defined are two styles for nodes used in graph: `tbox` for nodes with text with font size `tiny` and `fbox` for text with font size `\footnotesize`. By this the later code is shorter and more easy to read.
- `grid=both` is changed only with `grid` which do the same (not really esential for this answer)
- `xticklabels={, , , , , ,}` and similarly `yticklabels` are replaced with shorter `xticklabels={empty}`, which gives the same result.

[image]

Comment: What is `tbox` in the commands `\draw[fill] (4,0) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[tbox,below] {4};`?

Comment: Is the `4` typeset the same distance below the `x`-axis using a `node` command as using `extra x tick labels`?

Comment: @Adelyn, i'm sorry for stint explanations, I will add more of them to answer. for used node I define their styles as option to `tikzpicture`: `tbox` for nodes with `\tiny` font size and `fbox` for `footnotesize`. Your `extra x ticks` is on the same place as circle, which designate crossing of sloped line and x-axis, where is coordinate `4`.

Comment: Yes, I see that you defined styles for the nodes.  I missed that the first time I looked at your code.

Comment: How did you get the grid lines to be spaced by integral multiples of 5 along the both axes?  Is that the default?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be default settings.