# Displaying two graphs with the x-axes aligned and with titles centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have two plots of rational functions displayed separately on the Cartesian plane. Two modifications are needed; I think one modification will give both modifications.

I want the `x`-axes aligned.  I think the reason that they are not aligned is that the title under one plot occupies four lines and the title under the other plot occupies two lines.  How do I keep the displays of the titles as I have it and get the `x`-axes aligned?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[blue, domain=-10:-0.1] {1/x};
\addplot[blue, domain=0.1:10] {1/x};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the first rational function.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-0.3)$)
{\mbox{An illustration of the continuity of} \\
\mbox{a rational function defined on} \\
\mbox{the complement of a singleton} \\
\mbox{set in \boldmath$\mathbb{R}$\unboldmath}};

\end{tikzpicture}
%
\qquad \quad
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[blue, domain=-5:5] {x^3/(x^2 + 1)};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the second rational function.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-0.3)$)
{\mbox{An illustration of the continuity of} \\
\mbox{a rational function defined on \boldmath$\mathbb{R}$\unboldmath}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, that makes alignment easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=ax1,
    width=3in, height=3in, axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10,xmax=10,
    ymin=-10,ymax=10,
    restrict y to domain=-10:10,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[blue, domain=-10:-0.1] {1/x};
\addplot[blue, domain=0.1:10] {1/x};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the first rational function.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(ax1.south) +(0,-0.3)$)
{An illustration of the continuity of \\
a rational function defined on \\
the complement of a singleton \\
set in $\mathbb{R}$};

\begin{axis}[name=ax2,
    at={($(ax1.east) + (3em,0)$)},anchor=west,
    width=3in, height=3in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[blue, domain=-5:5] {x^3/(x^2 + 1)};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the second rational function.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(ax2.south) +(0,-0.3)$)
{An illustration of the continuity of \\
a rational function defined on $\mathbb{R}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the post at `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323421/removing-a-grid-line-and-shortening-the-remaining-grid-lines-in-a-pgfplots-displ`?